# SQL QUERY double full join and a nested join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have been struggling to make a single sql query that would give the result of all 3 queries in one. I suppose I would need to use full joins.
These 3 queries are all grouped by hour_key and store_id and ordered by hour_key.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The 3 queries are the following :

```
select SUM(qty_invoiced) as diag, DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%h') as hour_key, b.store_id
from sales_flat_order_item a inner join
    sales_flat_order b
    on (a.order_id = b.entity_id)
where a.created_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() AND
     a.parent_item_id IS NULL AND
     a.sku LIKE 'D-%' AND b.status in ('processing', 'complete', 'printed', 'ready_to_print', 'ready_to_ship')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%h'), b.store_id 
ORDER BY hour_key DESC
```

```
select SUM(grand_total) as grand_total, store_id , DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%h') as hour_key, SUM(shipping_amount) as shipping
from sales_flat_order
where created_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() AND status in ('processing', 'complete', 'printed', 'ready_to_print', 'ready_to_ship')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%h'), store_id
ORDER BY hour_key DESC
```

```
SELECT COUNT(a.entity_id) as totalPaniers, a.store_id, DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%h') as hour_key
FROM sales_flat_quote a
WHERE a.created_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%h'), a.store_id 
ORDER BY hour_key DESC
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  Desired results often help.

Comment: This is a useful guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example *(Especially the word **minimal**.)*

Comment: The logic is that each of these 3 separate queries are grouped on the same columns. I would like one single query that would give me the result of all 3 of the queries. I suppose by using full joins

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: 5.7.23 is my current version in MAMP

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what your table structure is, so my best guess is

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%h') as hour_key, 
  COUNT(entity_id) as totalPaniers, 
  store_id, 
  SUM(grand_total) as grand_total, 
  SUM(shipping_amount) as shipping,
  SUM(qty_invoiced) as diag
FROM
  sales_flat_quote a
  [LEFT] JOIN sales_flat_order b ON a.store_id=b.store_id
  INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item c ON c.order_id=b.entity_id
WHERE
  a.created_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() 
  AND b.created_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
  AND c.created_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
  AND b.`status` IN ('processing', 'complete', 'printed', 'ready_to_print', 'ready_to_ship')
  AND c.parent_item_id IS NULL 
  AND c.sku LIKE 'D-%' 
GROUP BY
  b.created_at, store_id
ORDER BY hour_key DESC
```